# Umbraco Examine - Querying Integers not Working

Tags: lucene, umbraco7, range-query, examine

I'm using Umbraco v.7.6.1 with Examine v0.1.82 (Lucene 2.9.4.1). I have a list of vehicles and a search form to query different types of fields, including Price. The Price field is a Numeric data field and in the ExamineIndex is defined as:

```
<add Name="price" Type="INT" />
```

The problem is when searching for a price range, I have no results. Using the Examine Management tool in the Umbraco backoffice with the following query:

```
+price:[50 TO 500000]
```

returns no results, even though I have vehicles in that price range.

If I change the Examine index and remove the Type="INT" tag from the price field, then the range query works as a normal string range query and returns results.

The query is working properly for all the string fields.

According to everything I've read in the documentation and previous questions/answers about Examine, this should work with the Examine version I'm using. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are looking in the back office after setting it to `INT` in `ExamineIndex.config` file under `IndexUserFields`. Back office will **not** show result for it if you pass straight query. I faced the same thing. You have to query throw code and it will show up the result.

Kindly set `<add Name="price" Type="Int" />` in the config file. I hope case wont have any issue like `INT` or `Int`.

Then Query from the code is like below

```
var searcher = Examine.ExamineManager.Instance.SearchProviderCollection["SearcherName"];
var searchCriteria = searcher.CreateSearchCriteria();

var query = searchCriteria.Range("price", 50, 500000, true, true);
var results = searcher.Search(query.Compile());
```

Kindly rebuild index before querying.